# find start and end date of previous month from current date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to find the start and end date of the previous month from the current date.

If the current date is `03-Feb-2021`

The start date should be `01-Jan-2021` and the end date should be `31-Jan-2021`.

how to achieve this as each month have a different number of days? Do we have any function in datetime to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried and what didn't work for you?

Comment: You could automate it, but as for months, they always have the same amount of days. Excluding february once every 4 years.
Consider hard coding it as the simplest solution ?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I tried long process. I made a list of dictionary ( { month: no of days). and then I run a loop to find the date. But I need a short method.

Comment: @Wiktoor Wut? What calendar are you following in which all months have the same amount of days?!

Comment: @deceze Same as yours? For example, January always has 31 days, April always has 30 days.

Comment: @superb Meh, okay, that rather read like `january.length == february.length == …`.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, but only until the "Excluding february ..." which I think clarifies it :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> this_first = date.today().replace(day=1)
>>> prev_last = this_first - timedelta(days=1)
>>> prev_first = prev_last.replace(day=1)
>>> prev_first, prev_last
(datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 31))
```

Format if/as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Get current date
today = datetime.date.today()

# Get first day of previous month
first_day = today.replace(day=1) - relativedelta(months=1)

# Get last day of previous month
last_day = today.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# Format dates
start = first_day.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
end = last_day.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

# Print dates
print("Start date:", start)
print("End date:", end)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76239525/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

first date will always be the 1st

```
# month_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=20))
month_date = datetime.now().replace(day= monthrange(month_date.year,month_date.month - 1)[1]).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
start_date = month_date.strftime("%Y/%m/01")
end_date = month_date.replace(day= monthrange(month_date.year,month_date.month)[1]).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

imports are

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange
```

you can add one condition for january so it will take december. If have any problem with that just add comment I will add that too.

Comment: `- timedelta(days=20)` won't find the previous month after the 21st of each month…

Comment: so whatever the today's date you can -1 the month. It will give you the start and end date of the month. you can put some conditions to get any date of the month you need the first and last date. let me edit it that way

Comment: Have you tried your code? `NameError: name 'month_date' is not defined`

Comment: *"so whatever the today's date you can -1 the month"* — How's that gonna work on March 31st for example?

Comment: I think I should go with the long method.

Comment: `monthrange(month_date.year, month_date.month - 1)` is going to be an error in January…