# How to get the start and end date for previous X months based on datetime.today() in python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I want get a list of start and end dates of the current + previous 4 months based on the current date.

Currently I manually update the list every month.

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = (
["2020-10-01", "2020-10-31"],
["2020-11-01", "2020-11-30"],
["2020-12-01", "2020-12-31"],
["2021-01-01", datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')])
```

How can I can get the same list as above but without manually adjusting the months?
Ideally I want to be able to create lists that go further back than the last 4 months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a similar question asked a couple of hours before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026812/find-start-and-end-date-of-previous-month-from-current-date-in-python?noredirect=1#comment116738585_66026812

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, thanks for sharing. However, I am not sure how that helps me with getting the start and end dates for the past 4 months in a list? Could you clarify? Much appreciated.

Comment: If you understand how the answer to this question works, you can easily expand it to several months.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, it appears I don't understand how that answer to that question works. Could you clarify it for me using my question? Much appreciated.

Comment: Then you need to read about [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) and about [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-timedelta).

Comment: related: [Python get months start and end dates for a given year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66118826/10197418)